# Is this a class variable?

Tags: python, oop

```py
class Activity(object):
    def __init__(self, name, duration, demand):
        self.duration = duration
        self.demand = demand
        self.name = name
        
    def __repr__(self):
        return self.name
    
    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.name == other.name
    
    def __hash__(self):
        return hash(self.name)
        
Activity.DUMMY_START = Activity("start",0, 0)
Activity.DUMMY_END = Activity("end",0, 0)
Activity.DUMMY_NODES = [Activity.DUMMY_START, Activity.DUMMY_END]
```

What does the Activity.DUMMY_START, Activity_DUMMY_END and Activity.DUMMY_NODES means. I think they are not class variables, they are outside. Is  it a good practice?

Moreover will  Activity.DUMMY_START, Activity_DUMMY_END and Activity.DUMMY_NODES be accessible from other files? how to import them properly?

Comment: @khelwood I've changed it

Comment: "I think they are not class variables, they are outside." - you can create class variables from outside the class statement.

Comment: They are class attributes; you are simply creating them after the class has been defined, rather than during class creation.

Comment: @chepner What is better to do? inside or outside?

Comment: For these, you *can't* initialize them inside the class statement, because `Activity` doesn't exist yet.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica is it a bad practice? is there an alternative ?

Comment: @JoffreyL. As he/she said, there isn't an alternative. These are instances of the class, and can only be created once the class has been defined. Although it's usually clearer to create class variables inside the class definition, it will still work if you create them afterwards. (I have a vague idea that in Python 3 it won't work if you monkey-patch *instance* methods and then try to call them, but that's not an issue here; it's the class that we are modifying.)

Comment: @alaniwi the ponit that I dont understand is that they are instances. I thought the syntax of defining an instance is var_name = Activyt(..) So why not just say DUMMY_START = Activity(..) ?

Comment: @alaniwi The issue with instance methods is that an instance method is really a class attribute with special behavior when accessed via an instance (i.e., they are descriptors). These aren't descriptors, just instances of `Activity`.

Comment: @JoffreyL. What you have is fine; the real question is whether `Activity` needs instances of itself (or a list of such instances) as class attributes, something we can't tell from the limited example here.

Comment: @chepner what's the difference with  `DUMMY_START = Activity(..)` ?

Comment: @JoffreyL. If you mean doing that inside the class, it won't work (the class isn't defined yet). If you mean outside the class, yes you can do that and then the class could use those variables from the module's namespace. But then those variables won't be accessible to external code via the class or instances of it, but instead by importing them from the containing module. Whether that matters or not is hard to say from what is here.

Comment: @alaniwi what if I say DUMM_START and DUMMY_END are special type of tasks? Is it better to just do DUMMY_START = Activity(...) outside of the class ?

Comment: @JoffreyL. wjandrea suggested that you take it to Code Review.

Answer (score 1):

Attributes assigned to the class namespace are class variables. This can happen in the class definition or after. In this case, the author wanted to create objects of the class itself in its own namespace. That can't be done in the class definition, but can be done afterwards as seen. This is the normal way to attach instances of a class to its own namespace.

To test whether this works, I've updated your program with a test method to get the. We can create an instance and see the variables the same as a standard class variables.

```
class Activity(object):
    def __init__(self, name, duration, demand):
        self.duration = duration
        self.demand = demand
        self.name = name
        
    def __repr__(self):
        return self.name
    
    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.name == other.name
    
    def __hash__(self):
        return hash(self.name)

    def test_dummy_start(self):
        return self.DUMMY_START
        
Activity.DUMMY_START = Activity("start",0, 0)
Activity.DUMMY_END = Activity("end",0, 0)
Activity.DUMMY_NODES = [Activity.DUMMY_START, Activity.DUMMY_END]

foo = Activity("active", 3, 2)
print(foo.DUMMY_START)
print(foo.test_dummy_start())
```

Answer (score 0):

They're class attributes. Names written in all caps are [meant to be constants](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#constants), so I wouldn't call them variables per se, though technically they are. They have to be outside the class definition because the class needs to exist before it can be referenced like `Activity("start", 0, 0)`.

Yes they will be accessible if you import `Activity`. You don't need to do anyhing special.

Whether it's good practice depends on the context, but the context is missing, so I can't really answer that, plus to an extent it's a matter of opinion. So that would probably be a better question for [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) than Stack Overflow, if you can provide the context.

Comment: what's the difference between DUMMY_START = Activity(...) and Activity.DUMMY_START = Activity(..) ?

Comment: @Joffrey Syntactically, one assigns to a name, the other assigns to an attribute